# Basic (working) tutorial calling C# code in Java using JNI

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface

As the title states, I'm looking for a basic (working) tutorial of Java code that uses JNI to call a "hello world" kind of application written in C#.

The "best" I found is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/javacsharp.aspx), but I can't get it to work following the tutorial + the ready to use projects don't build in Visual Studio 2008.

I have to say that I have no .NET knowledge apart from creating a basic project and writing C# code. Once I have working projects I'll do something similar with the DLL (and source code) I received.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) may be of use ? From the intro page:

```
import net.sf.jni4net.Bridge;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bridge.init();
        system.Console.WriteLine("Greetings from Java to .NET world!");
    }
}
```

So it *looks* pretty straightforward. Of course the devil is in the detail.

Comment: I already saw that, but I didn't want to add an extra layer of abstraction just to expose a few (10 - 20) C# methods to Java. Now that it seems impossible to find a basic working "hello world" example, I'll stick with this, thanks!

Comment: I have compiled this tutorial from my java-.net bridging experience, Hope it helps : http://codefry.blogspot.in/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html

Comment: Does invoking C# code from java mean I can also access C# libraries from java?

Comment: I would believe so, yes